# pubCenter Ads aren't showing up in trial version

Tags: windows-phone-8

Did I have to do something special when i submitted the app to the app store?  I noticed there was an optional section for adding a pubCenter ad but I didn't fill it in, however i created the ad in pubCenter and included the Ad control and entered the correct Ad ID to the control

Ads are not showing up.

Comment: Are they showing in the full version?

Comment: @PiRhAnAs no, i think I selected the wrong size, I read that if you select the wrong size for the ad in a XAML app the ads might not show up or get cut off.  I have to use the smaller recommended size of 320x50 I think, I'm going to try it later and see if it works  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-ad-size%28v=msads.20%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When debugging I had to use default values ( was using the actual application ID and adunit ID which is wrong)

```
     ApplicationId="test_client" 
     AdUnitId="Image320_50"
```

Furthermore I have to enable these capabilities in order for the ads to show up, after I enable them they worked !

[Required Manifest Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-manifest-capabilities%28v=msads.20%29.aspx)

Apps Targeting Windows Phone 8.0

The following ID_CAP capabilities must be included in the manifest of the advertising-enabled app.

•ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER

•ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO

•ID_CAP_NETWORKING

•ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER

•ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT